# GDPR Civicrm Bug when attempting to forward to another thank you page?

Tags: gdpr

On the Communications Preferences settings page (of the GDPR extension) the option to Display a message on the form page works fine, but when attempting to forward to another thank you page

https://peoples-press.com/thank-you

and I put either relative or absolute (which the extensions says I can) the page it sends me to is

https://peoples-press.com/index.php?option=com_civicrm&task=https://peoples-press.com/thank-you

Have no idea how to tackle

Civicrm 5.1 - Joomla 3.8.7

Answer (score 2):

thank you for reporting the problem. I tried to reproduce the problem on my website - it actually appears at absolute addresses. I link your entry, I will add my screenshots and create a problem notification in the plugin. Regards
Marcin Lewandowski
The Star of Life Foundation

EDIT - issue is [here](https://github.com/veda-consulting/uk.co.vedaconsulting.gdpr/issues/99)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether you have development skills or whether you have access to fund a developer.

Either way to process is to report an issue on the extension github page (https://github.com/veda-consulting/uk.co.vedaconsulting.gdpr). 
When you are a developer you could 'fork' the repository on github to your account, fix the bug, commit it to your repository, and then create a 'Pull Request'. Which then allows to original developer to incorporate your changes.